# Implementing Facebook's Graph API without user authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm newbie to **Facebook Graph API** and **Facebook JavaScript SDK** but I'd like to know some things:

- Is there any way to put my *Access Token* in a Open Source application without actually showing it? I'm using GitHub and for security purposes I'd like to make it private.
- Can I show my user information without asking the users to *Authenticate* themselves?
- Where in [Facebook Developers App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) can I allow more "scopes" to share publicly? For example, user_photos, user_posts, user_likes, user_status, etc...

These "scopes" that Facebook allows by default are actually the information I'm getting from the user while I'm *Authenticating* them right?

Just to clarify what I'm trying to do, I want to share things about my Facebook Account through the **Facebook Graph API** in the *gh-pages* branch on GitHub, but I don't like the idea of having to authenticate every single user that has access to the page.

I'd like to make my user information public, but don't want to show my access token, because it's Open Source and it can get dangerous eventually.

If you'd like to see my repository and have a better understanding of the project. You can access https://github.com/iszwnc/rye

Comment: user access tokens are valid for 2 hours only. extended user tokens are valid for 60 days. so why even bother adding a user token? what´s the point anyway? why not just add a link to your facebook profile? not sure what this whole question is about, to be honest...

Comment: @luschn you were very rude man... And first, you can create an Access Token by using the App ID and the Client Secret that is never going to expire

Comment: @luschn the point of why I'm doing this doesn't concern you. I just wanted a little help to see what I can do about it.  And seriously, you're not helping at all

Comment: @luschn perhaps I didn't help too much saying *User Access Token*, but still what I meant

Comment: i am not sure why you think that my comment would be rude, i only stated some facts...? you did say "user access token", there is no user access token that is valid forever. what you mean is an APP access token and you should not add that one to an open source project either. i am not sure why this would NOT be helpful either. if you want to get an answer, write a question we can actually answer. if you don´t tell us WHY you want to do this, we can´t give you a good answer that fits to your issue. so yes, it does concern us.

Comment: @luschn do you have any idea how to solve my question? Now that you know that i meant **App Access Token**?

Comment: i can only give you an answer if you tell me what exactly you want to achieve. "I want to share things about my Facebook Account through the Facebook Graph API in the gh-pages branch on GitHub" - that does not tell me much, what things do you want to share and how? please be more specific, some code would help too. and since it´s about an open source application, you could add a github url too.

Comment: @luschn I'll be doing an exchange program in Colombia through out an entire year. When I come back home I'll need to do a presentation about my trip

Comment: how is that related to facebook and/or the api? i´m sorry, but that makes the whole question even more unspecific...

Comment: @luschn i wanted to create a Page on GitHub that shares everything that I went living there, like post status, likes, check-ins, etc..

Comment: @luschn it'll help on my presentation you know? Sharing stuff that I went living in a more interactive way instead of just going to my Facebook Profile and looking up for pictures...

Comment: @luschn is through the Facebook API that I'll get the data to fill the GitHub Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recap:

- you don't want to share your app access token (good!),
- you don't want your users to authenticate.

Basically, you can't hide your token *and* let your users query Facebook directly. You **need** some server-side code on a machine that would be the only one reaching Facebook. Your server would play the role of an interface between Facebook and your users. So you will have to:

- do the API calls from a server using server-side code (i.e. Node.js),
- save the information you want in a database. This is optional but better to avoid the same information to be retrieved multiple times, thus avoiding your future 100 users to (voluntarily or not) reach your app API limit.
- let the users query *your* server using some client-side code (i.e. AngularJS) in order to retrieve what you and only you know (remember, you own the token).

---

About Github, don't share your token on it. People can generate their own token if they want to run your app. Here are several suggestions:

- Add your token to an environment variable which you can set just before launching the app (don't forget to mention that in your README),
- Add your token to a file:

  1. Create a `credentials.js` file that contains an empty token:

     ```
     // Please use your own token
     var APP_TOKEN = '';
     ```
  2. Commit the file to Github,
  3. Have a `.gitignore` file that contains the `credentials.js`,
  4. `var APP_TOKEN = 'now-you-can-put-your-token-here';`

Good luck with your project, it looks exciting :-)

Comment: Nice! Is the part of database really necessary? I was thinking about [Digital Ocean](https://digitalocean.com). But if I want to use the database I will need to buy a domain as well, right? To configure my *droplet*. Can't I in any way have access directly to Facebook?

Comment: Yes, you could avoid using a database: The client queries your server => Your server queries Facebook => Your server sends back the data to your client. You really have to think of 2 small apps here! 1 as a client and 1 as a server. You won't need to "buy a domain" but in any case you will need a place where to run your server-side code (other than your Github pages space). I don't know Digital Ocean but I strongly advice Heroku. You will find lots of documentation to get started if you want to use Node.js, which I also strongly advice for the server-side.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, do you think the free plan is a good choice in this case? Could you do an example of how would be, if I start using Node.js, Heroku and GitHub altogether? Because I'm a little confused on how should I organize the repository. What should be public, and what shouldn't? Or do you know some tutorial or blog post helpful here?

Comment: Perfectly! The only thing is that your app will need to sleep 6 hours a day. Knowing that the"dyno" needs 30 minutes to fall asleep, your app have good chances to be sleeping for more than 6 hours! Read more here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

Comment: You can Google these main steps: **1.** Create a Node.js app that retrieves data from the Facebook API. **2.** Add REST/API endpoints to your Node.js app using Express (i.e `myrotaryapp.herokuapp.com/get-pictures`). **3.** Create an AngularJS app that calls the publicly available REST/API endpoints of your Node.js app.